# Non-standart url in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC application like a bookshelf, that deployed on IIS.
To get information from i have to put in browser's address line something like bookshelf.com/book/. What have i do to change url from bookshelf.com/book/ to .bookshelf.com?

I try to use Url rewriting on IIS, but nothing be done...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> What have i do to change url from bookshelf.com/book/ to .bookshelf.com?

Configure your default route in `Global.asax` so that the default controller is `Book` instead of `Home`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Book", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This assumes that you have a BookController and an Index action:

```
public class BookController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now when someone requests `http://bookshelf.com/` this controller action will be executed.